# UIAlert shows two times in iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uialertview

I have been trying to show an alert for internet connection is available or not. Implemented code for checking the internet and it works fine. But, when the internet is not readable, I am trying to show alert but alert show twice.

here is the code tried:

```
   @objc func reachabilityChanged(_ note: NSNotification) {
     let reachability = note.object as! Reachability
     if reachability.connection != .unavailable {
         if reachability.connection == .wifi {
             print("Reachable via WiFi")
         } else {
             print("Reachable via Cellular")
         }
         } else {
             print("Not reachable")
         
         let alert = UIAlertController(title: "No Internet Connection", message: "Make sure your device is connected to the internet.", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
         alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil))
 //            self.window?.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        
        topMostViewController().present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        
  //            let alertVC = UIAlertController(title: "No Internet Connection" , message: "Make sure your device is connected to the internet.", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
  //            let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Okay", style: UIAlertAction.Style.cancel) { (alert) in
    ////                   exit(0) // Your code here
    //               }
 //               alertVC.addAction(okAction)
 //               DispatchQueue.main.async {
//                   var presentVC = self.window?.rootViewController
//                   while let next = presentVC?.presentedViewController {
//                       presentVC = next
//                   }
//                   presentVC?.present(alertVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
 //               }
     
             
         }
     }

 func topMostViewController() -> UIViewController {
  var topViewController: UIViewController? = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController
  while ((topViewController?.presentedViewController) != nil) {
  topViewController = topViewController?.presentedViewController
  }
  return topViewController!
  }
```

Comment: please check how many times this function get called ?

Comment: @jawadAli two time its calling

Comment: actually its function that is calling twice ... thats why you alert is presenting twice ... right ?

Comment: I have called function once only.

Comment: but its calling twice

Comment: where you are calling this function ?

Comment: IN scenedelegate sceneDidBecomeActive